# Changing from SQL Server Compact to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, mdriven

[image]

I am migrating my database from SQL Server Compact to SQL Server. I get this error in the designer. Connection string works, any hints on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your SQL Server is new there is nothing to evolve - you will need to create the initial schema. MDrivenServer does this for the first model version it sees.
Delete all model versions from MDrivenServer - then upload the current model once again -> db schema is created